# How can I get rid of banding in JavaFX gradients?

Tags: javafx, 2d, artifacts

I'm using the GraphicsContext of a JavaFX Canvas to draw gradients (linear as well as radial), some times using the alpha channel to layer gradients on top of each other. But since the color resolution is so low (8 bits per channel), I have very obvious and annoying banding artifacts on each and every one of the gradients, for instance as shown in the image below.

[image: banding example]

I would like to increase the color resolution so that the banding disappears. If that is not possible, I would be eager to know if there are different Java-compatible APIs/frameworks for creating 2D drawings - I don't need UI stuff, I just want to draw, display, and save images.

Thanks in advance for any useful advice!

Comment: Provide a [mcve] with the code you used to draw the gradient.

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Do you or your application's users possess hardware capable of displaying more than 8 bits per channel?  If so, what is the max bits per channel?

Comment: Here is a link to [check capability for 10-bit color display](http://tedlansingphotography.com/equipment/10-bit-color-depth-and-adobe-photoshop-cs6/#:~:text=Follow%20these%20steps%20to%20test%2010%20bit%20color,support%20the%2010%20bit%20color%20depth%20mode.%20) and a [test image](http://tedlansingphotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/10Bit-Test-Ramp.jpg).

Comment: Internally [JavaFX color component are represented as float values](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/javafx/scene/paint/Color.java#L1846), what makes you believe that JavaFX imposes an 8 bit per color limit on the color depth?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I understand now that I was mistaken about the 8 bit limit, and that my display is the culprit, not JavaFX.